# Uncompress *.Z files in a folder returns error

Tags: gzip, compression

To estract a single .Z file from a given folder I use `uncompress file.Z` in a terminal and it works flawlessy. If, in the same folder, I want to extract all the .Z files I use `uncompress "*.Z"` or `uncompress '*.Z'` or `uncompress \*.Z`. But they all give the same error:

```
`gzip: *.Z: No such file or directory`
```

Same story if I use the "extended" extension proper of each file, that is `file.fitz.Z`.
How do I uncompress all the .Z files? What is going wrong?

Comment: Why are you using various forms of quotes in your command lines around the `*.Z` glob? Perhaps see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67757/wildcards-inside-quotes

Comment: I was using different forms of quotes because I suspected that could be the problem, but in fact it is not.

Answer (score 0):

From the answer on [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412314/uncompressing-z-files-in-a-folder-returns-error), it simply works as:

```
uncompress *.Z
```

because all the quotes I have tried escape the `*` character, causing it to be interpreted literally instead of as a wildcard.